# New Install 16.04 cannot access the Shared Drive : Step by Step guide you would do?

Tags: networking, windows, samba, shared-folders

completely new install of 16.04 want to connect to Shared Drive on Windows Server 2012 R2 what are the usual step ones takes?

Many thanks for sharing your normal workflow when install a new image of Ubuntu.

Some details/experience:
Share works fine before re-install, also works fine on my Imac, the wiping and newly install (of same 16.04) suddenly not work.

I have done install of smbclient but get NT_STATUS_CONNECTION_RESET (in terminal smbclient -L {ip to server}

I cannot connect to Server in "file explorer" using smb://{ip to sever}
get the message: Unhandled error message: Failed to retrieve share list from server: Connection timed out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a fix, it seems the smb protocol is old in Ubuntu 16.04 so one need to make any server to accept incoming connection using this old SMB protocol.

found it here: http://forums.kerio.com/t/26684//

Change registry key on the Server to accept older versions of SMB
"
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\srv

Start REG_DWORD value should be set to 2 (instead of 3)

This key switches of any compatibility with old version of SMB. If key value is 3, then SMB compatible with SMB version 3 and above ONLY. "